# PDFBox 2.0.4 has different JAR files when downloaded from its site and when taken from Maven

Tags: pdfbox

If I use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

as instructed at https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/getting-started.html I don't get the classes at org.apache.pdfbox.tools and org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio (such as ImageIOUtil, JPEGUtil, MetaUtil, TIFFUtil and others).

However, if I download JAR file from http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/pdfbox/2.0.4/pdfbox-app-2.0.4.jar as directed from https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x, I get them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you got from maven is the pdfbox download. What you got from the download URL (where you might notice 10 different downloads) is pdfbox-app, which is for the command line tools (and contains everything). These are different downloads. If you want ImageIOUtil, JPEGUtil, MetaUtil, TIFFUtil, then get pdfbox-tools as an addition to the pdfbox artifact.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I wish it was explained on the site, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I must admit that you're right... I don't have a good idea where to mention it (getting started or dependencies or ...). If you have a good idea, please post to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3330 It is mentionen in the https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html site, but that one is read only by "migrants".

Comment: Now I see it on Migration page. It could be mentioned on "Getting Started" page under Maven.

Comment: But how did the wish to have these classes come up? The getting started page is for newbies, obviously.